# Face-Gauss Divergence Theorem proof

Tags: proof-writing

How one can proof that

$\int_{\Omega}\nabla \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{t}  \,d\Omega = 
 (\oint_{\partial\Omega}\mathbf{u} \otimes \mathbf{m} \,dL) \cdot \mathbf{t}$,

where $\mathbf{u}$ is a vector field, $\Omega$ a polygon (i.e., flat and has piecewise smooth boundary) in the 3d-Euclidean space with normal $\mathbf{n}$, $\mathbf{m}$ is outward-facing unit normal (to the boundary) field  and the vector $\mathbf{t}$ is any constant vector such that $\mathbf{t} \cdot \mathbf{n}=0$?

**A draft**:

1) Suppose that $\Omega$ is a rectangle (the polygon case can easily be solved by subdividing it).

2) Apply a coordinate transformation such that:

1. $\Omega$ becomes $\underline{\Omega}$, which is co-planar and aligned to the xy-plane;
2. $\mathbf{t}$ becomes $\underline{\underline{\mathbf{t}}}$, which lies on $\underline{\Omega}$;
3. $\mathbf{u}$ becomes $\underline{\underline{\mathbf{u}}}$.

3) Then,

$\int_{\Omega}\nabla \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{t}  \,d\Omega$ becomes $\int_{\underline{{\Omega}}} \nabla \underline{\underline{\mathbf{u}}}  \cdot \underline{\underline{\mathbf{t}}} \,d\Omega \quad$ (I)

4) Write $\underline{\underline{\mathbf{u}}}
 =  
   \underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} \mathbf{e}_{1}
 + \underline{\underline{u}}_{t2} \mathbf{e}_{2}
 + \underline{\underline{u}}_{n}  \mathbf{e}_{3}$, where $\{\mathbf{e}_i\}$ is the canonical 3d-Euclidean base, $\underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} = \underline{\underline{\mathbf{u}}} \cdot \mathbf{e}_{1}$, $\underline{\underline{u}}_{t2} = \underline{\underline{\mathbf{u}}} \cdot \mathbf{e}_{2}$ and $\underline{\underline{u}}_{n} = \underline{\underline{\mathbf{u}}} \cdot \mathbf{e}_{3}$. Thus, and since $\underline{\underline{\mathbf{t}}}$ is constant,

$
  \int_{\underline{{\Omega}}} \nabla \underline{\underline{\mathbf{u}}}  \cdot \underline{\underline{\mathbf{t}}} \,d\Omega 
  = 
\left[ 
  \int_{\underline{{\Omega}}} \nabla 
  \left( 
    \underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} \mathbf{e}_{1}
     + \underline{\underline{u}}_{t2} \mathbf{e}_{2}
     + \underline{\underline{u}}_{n}  \mathbf{e}_{3}
  \right)
  \,d\Omega 
\right]
\cdot \underline{\underline{\mathbf{t}}} \quad
$ (II).

5) As a corollary from **2d**-divergence theorem, we have that

$\int_{\underline{\Omega}} \nabla \underline{u}(x,y) \,d\Omega
  = 
    \oint_{\partial\underline{\Omega}} \underline{u}(x,y) \underline{\mathbf{m}} \,dL. \quad$ (III)

6) Focusing only on one piece of (II), we have that,

$
\left[
\int_{\underline{{\Omega}}} \nabla 
  \left( 
    \underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} \mathbf{e}_{1}
  \right)
  \,d\Omega
\right] \cdot \underline{\underline{\mathbf{t}}}
=
\left[
\mathbf{e}_{1} \otimes
\int_{\underline{{\Omega}}} \nabla 
  \underline{\underline{u}}_{t1}
  \,d\Omega
\right] \cdot \underline{\underline{\mathbf{t}}}
=
\left[
\int_{\underline{{\Omega}}} \nabla 
  \underline{\underline{u}}_{t1}
  \cdot \underline{\underline{\mathbf{t}}}
  \,d\Omega
\right]
\mathbf{e}_{1}
=
\left[
\int_{\underline{{\Omega}}}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \underline{\underline{t}}_x \\
    \underline{\underline{t}}_y \\
    0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \,d\Omega
\right]
\mathbf{e}_{1}
=
\left[
\int_{\underline{{\Omega}}}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} \underline{\underline{t}}_x +
    \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} \underline{\underline{t}}_y
  \,d\Omega
\right]
\mathbf{e}_{1}
=
\left[
\int_{\underline{{\Omega}}}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\underline{\underline{u}}_{t1} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \underline{\underline{t}}_x \\
    \underline{\underline{t}}_y \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \,d\Omega
\right]
\mathbf{e}_{1}
. \quad$ (IV)

The last term of the equation above suggests us to define 
$
  \underline{u}(x,y) = \underline{\underline{u}}(x,y,0)
$, 
$
  \underline{\mathbf{t}} = [\underline{\underline{t}}_x \; \underline{\underline{t}}_y ]^T
$ and redefine $\mathbf{e}_{1}$ to be $[1 \; 0]^T$ in order to write the 2d version of this term. Now we can apply the corollary like this:

$
\left[
\int_{\underline{{\Omega}}} \nabla 
  \underline{u}_{t1}
  \cdot \underline{\mathbf{t}}
  \,d\Omega
\right]
\mathbf{e}_{1}
=
\left[
\mathbf{e}_{1}
\otimes
\int_{\underline{{\Omega}}} \nabla 
  \underline{u}_{t1}
  \,d\Omega
\right]
\cdot \underline{\mathbf{t}}
\stackrel{\text{(III)}}{=}
\left[
\mathbf{e}_{1}
\otimes
\oint_{\partial\underline{{\Omega}}}
  \underline{u}_{t1} \,
  \underline{\mathbf{m}}
  \,dL
\right]
\cdot \underline{\mathbf{t}}
=
\left[
\oint_{\partial\underline{{\Omega}}}
  (\underline{\mathbf{m}} \cdot \underline{\mathbf{t}})
  \underline{u}_{t1} \mathbf{e}_{1}\,
  \,dL
\right].
$

Of course the process is analogous for $\underline{u}_{t2}$. I will write the rest of the proof when someone says it is ok up until this point.

Comment: Hello @Malkoun. Sorry, I forgot to say who is $\mathbf{n}$ (is normal to the polygon), it is edited now.  Note that $\partial \Omega$ is a piecewise boundary curve, thus it has a normal field, this is $\mathbf{m}$.
Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think, though I did not check carefully, that what you are considering amounts to the fundamental theorem of calculus component-wise, if I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: I thought at first that I could apply the fundamental theorem of calculus component-wise, but it seems this is not the case, since $\Omega$ might not be co-planar to any of the planes xy xz yz.

Comment: You can rotate the coordinates and choose new coordinates such that in the new coordinates, say, the polygon lies in $z=c$, where $c$ is constant, and you can also have $\mathbf{t}$ be parallel to the new $x$-axis.

Comment: Humm, I see it, but I cannot give a formal proof for it since my math is not very good. Can you?

Comment: Sorry, I gave you basically the idea. Try to formalize it into a proof.

Comment: I have the intuition, but not the necessary math skills. Anyway, thank you for the valuable tips.

Comment: Sorry, but my students are sending me many questions as the final exams are quite soon.

Comment: @Malkoun When you have time, could you take a look at my draft? Thank you.